# Javascript chart which can plot values from a txt file

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I found a code of a Javascript chart for my html webpage(see code below). And that part works fine.
But for the next step I would like that the chart get its values from a txt file.
I have no clue how to start with that. Anyone who can help me out?

I also have a second question(less important), i want to put units to the values, I tried some solutions on the internet but nothing seems to work for me???

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Multiple Y Axis Chart</title>

    <link href="../../assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <style>
      
        #chart {
      max-width: 650px;
      margin: 35px auto;
    }
    .apexcharts-tooltip-title {
      display: none;
    }
    #chart .apexcharts-tooltip {
      display: flex;
      border: 0;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
      
    </style>

    <script>
      window.Promise ||
        document.write(
          '<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js"><\/script>'
        )
      window.Promise ||
        document.write(
          '<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eligrey-classlist-js-polyfill@1.2.20171210/classList.min.js"><\/script>'
        )
      window.Promise ||
        document.write(
          '<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/findindex_polyfill_mdn"><\/script>'
        )
    </script>

    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
    

    
  </head>

  <body>
     <div id="chart"></div>

    <script>
      
        var options = {
          series: [{
          name: 'Humidity',
          type: 'line',
          data: [1.4, 2, 2.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.8, 3.8, 4.6]
        }, {
          name: 'Temperature',
          type: 'line',
          data: [1.1, 3, 3.1, 4, 4.1, 4.9, 6.5, 8.5]
        },
],
          chart: {
          height: 350,
          type: 'line',
          stacked: false
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        stroke: {
          width: [1, 1, 4]
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Temperature and humidity',
          align: 'left',
          offsetX: 110
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: [0601, 0701, 0801, 0901, 0801, 0901, 1001, 1101],
        },
        yaxis: [
          {
            axisTicks: {
              show: true,
            },
            axisBorder: {
              show: true,
              color: '#008FFB'
            },
            labels: {
              style: {
                colors: '#008FFB',
              }
            },
            title: {
              text: "Humidity in % ",
              style: {
                color: '#008FFB',
              }
            },
            tooltip: {
              enabled: true
            }

          },
          {
            seriesName: 'Humidity in %',
            opposite: true,
            axisTicks: {
              show: true,
            },
            axisBorder: {
              show: true,
              color: '#00E396'
            },
            labels: {
              style: {
                colors: '#00E396',
              }
            },
            title: {
              text: "Temperature in °C",
              style: {
                color: '#00E396',
              }
            },
          },
          
        ],
        tooltip: {
          fixed: {
            enabled: true,
            position: 'topLeft', // topRight, topLeft, bottomRight, bottomLeft
            offsetY: 30,
            offsetX: 60
          },
        },
        legend: {
          horizontalAlign: 'left',
          offsetX: 40
        }
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();
      
      
    </script>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

The txt file contains the values:
2
4
8
10
12
14
16
etc

Comment: Do you just want to get the text file values into an array like you have for temperature and humidity? string.split would be a good start (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: @quilkin Hi.I want to get the values of the text file into my chart. And the values of the txt file will updated by python

Comment: ApexCharrts accepts data in Json format (as other chart libraries do). See (https://apexcharts.com/docs/update-charts-from-json-api-ajax/). So you need to convert your text file into Json-formatted data first (or create it in Json first, rather than a long string of plain text? There's plenty of help available about Json

Comment: Hi, I looked at the link and tried an example but it doesnt seem to work?